# Where to start learning about Android Vpn?

Tags: android, udp, vpn, tcp, handshake

Looking around the Android API, I noticed the VpnService.  I thought it was pretty cool and I wanted to learn about it to see what kind of apps would be possible with it, so I started looking around for tutorials and explanations.

I discovered that I know *nothing* about what the different methods are for, why they work, or how to manipulate them. Words and phrases like TCP/UDP, network interface, TUN, and handshake popped out at me, but overall, I have no idea how these things actually work or how to use them.  Could I get a point in the right direction to maybe a book or website where I could learn the basics about this stuff and work my way up to the more advanced things like Android Vpn?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn from Wiki otherwise there are many VPN or tutorial sites you can found through google just search them and read about android vpn and how you can setup vpn on android.